# -webkit-box-flex: 1; not working when used with display: -webkit-flex;

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using the new `display: -webkit-flex;` syntax for defining 'flexboxes', but I can't get the `-webkit-box-flex: 1;` working, so an element takes the remaining space.

When I use `display: box;`, the old syntax, it works fine (example on http://flexiejs.com/playground/ ). Can I use suggest, that chrome supports the new standard (http://flexiejs.com/playground/ ).

In Firefox it works fine (can't test it in IE right now)

Here is my sample code ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khAa4/1/) ):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .wrapper {
            /* old syntax */
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-box;
            /* new syntax */
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -moz-flex;
            display: -o-flex;
            display: -ms-flex;
            display: flex;
            border: 1px solid;
        }

        html, body, .wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .element {
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            min-width: 300px;
            -moz-box-flex: 1;
            -webkit-box-flex: 1;
            box-flex: 1;
        }

        .no-flexbox .wrapper .element {
            float: left;
            width: 300px;
        }

        .no-flexbox .wrapper .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        .flexbox .wrapper .clear {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="element">
            <h1>hello world</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum<br />
                Lorem ipsum
            </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            <h1>hello world</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum
            </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The different flexbox syntaxes aren't compatible with one another.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks  @BoltClock .

If I use display: `-webkit-flex;` I, of course have to use `-webkitx-flex: 1;` instead of `-webkit-box-flex: 1;` !

Code update ([Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/EDqwe/) ):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Library zum erkennen von html5 features -->
    <script src="modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /*Elemente im wrapper werden nebeneinader angeordnet*/
        /*da es nicht nicht fertig standardisert ist, gibt es pro browser eine andere schreibweise,
            "display: flex;" ist die aktuellste und jene die in zukunkft alle verweneden sollten*/
        .wrapper {
            /* old syntax */
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-box;
            /* new syntax */
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -moz-flex;
            display: -o-flex;
            display: -ms-flex;
            display: flex;
            border: 1px solid;
        }

        html, body, .wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .element {
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            min-width: 300px;
            -moz-box-flex: 1;
            -webkit-flex: 1;
            -moz-flex: 1;
            -ms-box-flex: 1;
            box-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
        }

        /* no-flexbox wird von modernizr hinzugefügt wenn flex nicht utnerstützt ist*/
        .no-flexbox .wrapper .element {
            float: left;
            width: 300px;
        }

        .no-flexbox .wrapper .clear {
            clear: both;
        }
        /* flexbox wird von modernizr hinzugefügt wenn flex nicht utnerstützt ist*/
        /* clear tag wird nicht benötigt, da elemente mit flexbox angeordnet sind */
        .flexbox .wrapper .clear {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="element">
            <h1>hello world</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum<br />
                Lorem ipsum
            </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            <h1>hello world</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum
            </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```